# How best to integrate AWS Cognito authentication with Meteor

Tags: react-native, meteor, amazon-cognito

I am going to be working on a project that requires both a web app and react native mobile app which share a user accounts/login system.

My preferred web stack is Meteor with the accounts package, while for react native apps I have found that AWS Cognito works well as the login/authentication provider.

However I'm struggling to figure out how I would best integrate Cognito with Meteor to replace the default Accounts package.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!